# Saving as/export results of GeoVisual Search (Descartes Labs)

Tags: geoprocessing, imagery, satellite, descartes-labs-platform

I am working with satellite imagery processing.

I'm using this service to search for some objects in the US:

[https://search.descarteslabs.com](https://search.descarteslabs.com/)

Can I export about 1k results, for example, to KML or CSV/TXT with geographic coordinates?

Or, maybe, there are other services for finding some objects on satellite imagery (area of the US) with a possibility to save/export results of this searching.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, with caveats (full disclosure, I am a Descartes Labs employee).

- Geovisual Search is not part of the Descartes Labs Platform and any results you collect via the site are subject to the Descartes Labs website [Terms of Service](https://www.descarteslabs.com/terms-of-service/).
- Geovisual Search is an index of visual similarity - not a model trained to find specific objects or  patterns. For the complete methodology, see [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02624).

That said - each search of the index returns 1000 results ordered by similarity within the index. This is served by a JSON API at `https://search.descarteslabs.com/search?key={key}&{layer}&limit={limit}` where `key` is a UTM [DLTile identifier](https://docs.descarteslabs.com/guides/raster.html#dltiles), `layer` is an identifier for the dataset indexed, and `limit` is the number of results to return.

If all you need is a the list of tiles returned on the left - you can get that JSON response by looking in your browser's developer console to find the request made by the API. The result will be a list of GeoJSON features, with a `distance` property that corresponds to the visual similarity relative to the key tile (lower is more similar). This will include 1,000 results by default:

```js
"features":[
   {"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{"distance":0,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3650:56342"},
     "geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48853126199128,32.56553667302686],[-107.48720082953817,32.56553667302686],[-107.48720082953817,32.56671724913455],[-107.48853126199128,32.56671724913455],[-107.48853126199128,32.56553667302686]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":0,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3649:56353"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48802537553277,32.571894941909456],[-107.48669484774975,32.571894941909456],[-107.48669484774975,32.57307551646963],[-107.48802537553277,32.57307551646963],[-107.48802537553277,32.571894941909456]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":3,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3643:56348"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.4838586894654,32.56909183457887],[-107.48252814297841,32.56909183457887],[-107.48252814297841,32.57027236609133],[-107.4838586894654,32.57027236609133],[-107.4838586894654,32.56909183457887]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":3,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3645:56345"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48517328714188,32.56733449119291],[-107.48384278325798,32.56733449119291],[-107.48384278325798,32.568515034838654],[-107.48517328714188,32.568515034838654],[-107.48517328714188,32.56733449119291]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":3,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3651:56345"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48926022103753,32.56725357076538],[-107.48792977482196,32.56725357076538],[-107.48792977482196,32.56843415507681],[-107.48926022103753,32.56843415507681],[-107.48926022103753,32.56725357076538]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":3,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3651:56347"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48929210170445,32.568407165664674],[-107.48796163990536,32.568407165664674],[-107.48796163990536,32.56958775092752],[-107.48929210170445,32.56958775092752],[-107.48929210170445,32.568407165664674]]],"type":"Polygon"}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"distance":4,"key":"64:32:1.0:13:-3650:56357"},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-107.48877032562693,32.574188636091414],[-107.4874397762816,32.574188636091414],[-107.4874397762816,32.57536921933257],[-107.48877032562693,32.57536921933257],[-107.48877032562693,32.574188636091414]]],"type":"Polygon"}},
...
```